# Is there a standard way of cyclically rotating mutable variables in Rust?

Tags: rust, swap

A very common operation in implementing algorithms is the cyclic rotate: given, say, 3 variables a, b, c change them to the effect of

```
t ⇽ c
c ⇽ b
b ⇽ a
a ⇽ t
```

Given that everything is bitwise swappable, cyclic rotation should be an area where Rust excels more than any other language I know of.

For comparison, in C++ the most efficient generic way to rotate N elements is performing n+1 `std::move` operations, which in turn roughly leads to (for a typical move constructor implementation) `3 (n+1) sizeof(T)` word assignments (this can be improved for PODs via template specializing rotate, but requires work).

In Rust, the language makes it possible to implement rotate with only `(n+1) size_of(T)` word assignments. To my surprise, I could not find standard library support for rotation. (No rotate method in `std::mem`). It would probably look like this:

```rust
pub fn rotate<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T, z: &mut T) {
    unsafe {
        let mut t: T = std::mem::uninitialized();
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&*z, &mut t, 1);
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&*y, z, 1);
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&*x, y, 1);
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&t, x, 1);
        std::mem::forget(t);
    }
}
```

---

For clarification on why rotation cannot be implemented efficiently in C++, consider:

```cpp
struct String {
  char *data1;
  char *data2;
  String(String &&other) : data1(other.data1), data2(other.data2)
    { other.data1 = other.data2 = nullptr;}
  String &operator=(String &&other)
    { std::swap(data1, other.data1); std::swap(data2, other.data2);
      return *this; }
  ~String() { delete [] data1; delete [] data2; }
};
```

Here an operation like `s2 = std::move(s1);` will take 3 pointer assignments for each member field, totaling to 6 assignments since pointer swap requires 3 assignments (1 into temp, 1 out of temp, one across operands)

Comment: "*which in turn roughly leads to (for a typical move constructor implementation) `3 (n+1) sizeof(T)` word assignments*" Why? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Acorn A typical move constructor invokes swap on every member field. For PODs, like `int`, the swap takes only 3 assignments like so: `int t = other.val; other.val = val; val = t;`

Comment: @Acorn My above comment explains the factor 3. For the factor (n+1) consider the example I gave with variables a, b, c. This has 3 variables and 4 assignments (moves). This generalizes to n variables and n+1 moves.

Comment: I don't understand what you asking

Comment: @Stargateur The special case of rotation with 2 variables is called `swap`. I am asking for the general case with `n`  variables. Again, please take a look at the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say `rotate` can't be implemented as efficiently in C++ -- surely you can just use `memcpy` to avoid calling any move constructors? Sure, it's not always valid to do so, but it's exactly what you're doing with `copy_nonoverlapping` in Rust. Don't get me wrong, the Rust version is *better* since it can't be misused to cause UB, but it should be simple to make an equally *efficient* version in C++.

Comment: @trentcl In C++ you can use `memcpy` when the type satisfies certain constraints (that's what I'm referring to when I said rotate can be template specialized to PODs for extra efficiency). But for the toy `String` class I gave, C++ will incur a factor of 3 inefficiency. In Rust *every* type is byte swappable, so the rotate implementation I wrote using `copy_nonoverlapping` is valid for *every* type.

Comment: @trentcl The core of this issue stems from the fact that C++ structs are allowed to contain pointers to themselves whereas in Rust this is invalid. Due to this, in C++ you cannot safely swap things without invoking their move constructor (3 times).

Comment: @boinkboink First of all, I think you mean move assignment for `rotate`, not move constructor. Second, using `std::swap` is just a simple way to implement move assignment, but [it is not efficient](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html). Finally, the fact that some C++ types have restrictions does not mean it cannot be optimized for `TriviallyCopyable` types. In other words, it is not a valid comparison.

Comment: @Acorn The temporary *is* move constructed. The other two operations (out of 3) are move assign, you are correct in that. How do you implement a `rotate` in C++with (n+1) operations that works for every type. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @boinkboink Sure, it *may* be (not necessarily, though; e.g. you could create the temporary first if possible and then move assign to it), but the core operations are *required* to be move assignment. Again, you can do it in C++ for every type where it is allowed. You cannot argue that "C++ is inefficient" because some types are made non-trivially copyable (something done on purpose).

Comment: By the way, claiming that `copy_nonoverlapping` is valid for every type in Rust is a bit misleading. It is the same as claiming that in C++ you can call `memcpy` for any valid pointer. It is true, yet that is not the whole story: both of them are `unsafe` calls, and in both C++ or Rust the call to `rotate` is restricted in some way (i.e. not valid/correct in all situations and/or for all values).

Comment: @Acorn I disagree with this. In c++ you can do `struct A { char a; char *p; A() : p(&a) {} }; `. Can you do this in Rust?

Comment: @boinkboink That class can be trivially copied, so it does not apply to this problem. Again, the fact that C++ allows to create types that shouldn't be copied byte-by-byte (typically because they manage a resource of some kind) does not put any restrictions on creating types that can be. For such types, the implementation goes down to the (n+1) assignments that you mention. For those that aren't, it depends on what they do, so you cannot say it takes 3 (n+1). If you really want, you can code all your program using such types -- but it is not usually done like that in C++.

Comment: @Acorn This is an example of a class that *cannot* be memcopied. I think you are missing something here.

Comment: @boinkboink Nope. That class *can* be `memcpy`'d.

Comment: @Acorn What happens if it has a method printA() { printf("%c", *p); }. I think understanding this will clear the misunderstanding going on between us.

Comment: @boinkboink It will print the character where `p` points. The fact that the pointer may or may not point to the `c` of the same object does not mean the class is not `memcpy`able.

Comment: [Proof of concept](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/878cda40e605eece): although the compiler issues warnings about the `memcpy`s, it's exactly as safe and does the same thing as the Rust version for equivalent types. The fact that Rust forbids calling `rotate` with certain arguments is a *limitation* of Rust that C++ doesn't have.

Comment: @trentcl It's so hard being new here. As I alluded to earlier, structs having pointers to themselves are the only structs in c++ that cannot be bitwise swappable. String class I mentioned above is *not* such a class. But the compiler cannot know whether data2 is pointing to inside String or not so has to be defensive.

Comment: As opposed to Rust, where everything is bit swappable by design

Comment: My claim was 'How do you implement a rotate in C++with (n+1) operations that works for every type. I don't think this is possible.' You can do this for particular structs, just not generically.

Comment: In the question, it sounds like you're saying Rust *allows* something that C++ *forbids*, which is why you can write `rotate` this way. In fact, you can write `rotate` the same way in both languages, but Rust will *forbid* using it inappropriately, while C++ will *allow* you to shoot yourself in the foot. That's the only point I am trying to make.

Comment: (And, of course, if you really want to, you can still shoot yourself in the foot with Rust -- it just takes slightly more effort.)

Comment: @Acorn Everything is memcopiable if you don't require it to function correctly afterwards. You can memcopy things setting member variables with `new`.

Comment: @boinkboink The class you provided does function correctly afterwards. If *you* want to create a class with an invariant that `p` remains pointing to the `c` member, then C++ allows you to provide custom copy/move operations. That is what makes it non-`memcpy`able.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a standard way of cyclically rotating mutable variables in Rust?

No.

I'd just swap the variables twice, no need for `unsafe`:

```
use std::mem;

pub fn rotate<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T, z: &mut T) {
    mem::swap(x, y);
    mem::swap(y, z);
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    let mut b = 2;
    let mut c = 3;

    println!("{}, {}, {}", a, b, c);
    // 1, 2, 3

    rotate(&mut a, &mut b, &mut c);

    println!("{}, {}, {}", a, b, c);
    // 2, 3, 1
}
```

---

This produces 7 `movl` instructions (Rust 1.35.0, Release, x86_64, Linux)

```
playground::rotate:
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    movl    (%rsi), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rdi)
    movl    %eax, (%rsi)
    movl    (%rdx), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rsi)
    movl    %eax, (%rdx)
    retq
```

As opposed to the original 6 `movl` instructions:

```
playground::rotate_original:
    movl    (%rdx), %eax
    movl    (%rsi), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rdx)
    movl    (%rdi), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rsi)
    movl    %eax, (%rdi)
    retq
```

I'm OK giving up that single instruction for purely safe code that is also easier to reason about.

---

In "real" code, I'd make use of the fact that all the variables are the same type and that [`slice::rotate_left`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_left) and [`slice::rotate_right`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_right) exist:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vals = [1, 2, 3];

    let [a, b, c] = &vals;
    println!("{}, {}, {}", a, b, c);
    // 1, 2, 3

    vals.rotate_left(1);

    let [a, b, c] = &vals;
    println!("{}, {}, {}", a, b, c);
    // 2, 3, 1
}
```

Comment: This you can do in any language. What rust allows for is the elimination of the 3 fold inefficiency in this method. Doing it this way uses `3(n-1) * size_of(T)` word assignments.

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you! I'm pleasantly surprised you called it `rotate` since you mentioned earlier nobody would call it rotate. Also it turns out something similar is rotate_left/right in rust standard library, so this is not a rust terminology diversion.

Comment: @Stargateur OP's original code uses generics. The version you have there does not work for any generic type, but only for those that implement `Copy`, a rather small set of all types. Perhaps that's what the OP means by "bitwise swappable"?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes that code requires Copy trait. Furthermore, in both your alternative solution and this solution, manual swapping *seems* efficient but you demonstrate this just for small primitive types like i32. What's more interesting is what happens when the type is a huge struct.